# Express less-middleware not compiling

Tags: node.js, express

Can someone please help me get my css compiling. I don't know why my view is not getting the compiled less

### Index.js

```
// MIDDLEWARE
var express = require('express');
var less = require('less-middleware');
var app = express();

// LESS COMPILER
app.use(less('source/less', {
  "dest": 'public/stylesheets',
  "pathRoot": __dirname,
  "force": true,
  "render": {
    "yuicompress": true
  }
}));

// APP CONFIG
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', 'views')
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// ROUTES
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

// PAGE NOT FOUND
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).send('Sorry cant find that!');
});

// WEB SERVER
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

### Index.jade

```
html
  head
    title Hello
    link(src="stylesheets/global.css" type="text/css")
  body
    h1 Welcome
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about how to set the src and dest dirs for your less-middleware to different directories at https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware/wiki/Examples. But the upshot is this: To keep things relatively straightforward, the relative path of your source and dest must be identical.

I would recommend moving your less source files out of `public` to make this easier and because they're not supposed to be served as-is anyway.

Create a `less-src` dir in the same directory that has your `public` directory. Inside `less-src`, create a `stylesheets` directory and put your `global.less` in there. Then change your less middleware use to this:

```
app.use(lessMiddleware(__dirname + '/less-src', 
    {dest: __dirname + '/public'}));
```

And that will work.

If you dislike having a `stylesheets` directory in `less-src`, then you need to look at the material about preprocessing the less path at the the link above. To me, that trades code complexity for very little gain in terms of source code layout. But if it seems worth it to you, then that's how you can do it.

Comment: I took your advice and moved the src from public but this is still not working

Comment: Did you also change your `app.use()`. I got your exact code working with just that change.

Comment: I updated my code in my question to what I have now, and still not working.  Do I need less on my system to use the middleware?

Comment: And your less file is at `less-src/stylesheets/global.less`?

Comment: it is at `source/less/global.less` and in my jade i am calling it at `stylesheets/global.css`

Comment: That will not work. The subdirectories need to match or else you need to do the path preprocessing stuff.

Comment: Please explain to me what that means. I got it to work but I don't understand why

Comment: The src and dest dirs are basically docroot. So, a browser request for http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/global.css will cause express to look for `less-src/stylesheets/global.less` and, if it finds it, compile it into `public/stylesheets/global.css`. If you don't want the subdirectory paths to match, you have to preprocess them in code.