# Express less-middleware not compiling while using Pug view engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, less, pug

I'm pretty new to using Express and Pug but I know this should be pretty simple.

I'm trying to get my Pug views to use css files that are compiled by the less-middleware module but I can't seem to get less-middleware to compile my less files into css.

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const lessMiddleware = require('less-middleware');
const app = express();
...
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views','./views');
app.use(lessMiddleware(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
...
```

**home.pug**

```
html
    head
        title title
        link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/style.css")
```

**File Structure**

```
/public
    style.less
/src
    index.js
/views
    ...
    home.pug
```

Going to `http://localhost:3000/home` brings up this error message:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/public/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Now I know that this means that the style.css file isn't there (I think) and that stems from the less-middleware not compiling the less into css right?

I know this is practically a carbon copy of other questions like: [Express less-middleware not compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30181220/express-less-middleware-not-compiling) but I've tried everything I can and I'm out of ideas.

Apologies if this is really dumb/simple but I feel as if I'm bashing my head against a brick wall trying to solve this now. Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: `href="../public/style.css"` does not look correct to me.  From your file structure, it looks like it should be `href="/style.css"` because it's directly in the `/public` directory that `express.static()` is pointed at.

Comment: So I figured out the problem, because the ```index.js``` file was inside the ```/src``` folder, the ```__dirname``` resolved to ```D:/path/to/project/src``` and then I was appending ```/public``` to it making it look for the less file in ```D:/path/to/project/src/public```. Moving my ```index.js``` up a level to the base folder solved all my problems. Thanks for the comment though

Comment: You can either write your own answer to answer your own question (if you think the solution would be useful to others) or you can delete your question - your choice.